# Woocommerce REST API image upload woocommerce_rest_invalid_remote_image_url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am sending a valid jpeg url in woocommerce api to an IIS server that has passes all the tests in Woocommerce status except php version (which is 5.5). The remote get and remote post work.

I get the error:

Error getting remote image http://validsite.com/index.php/app_files/view/41?timestamp=1502249414. Error: A valid URL was not provided.. [woocommerce_rest_invalid_remote_image_url]

The url is a jpeg. What could cause this and/or how can I debug?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the wordpress either by plugin or core didn't allow requests to url outside of the domain it is installed on or local ip addresses. I Installed plugin https://github.com/UCF/WP-Allowed-Hosts and added host I was getting images from as an allowed host

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but I found it - and in case others ends up with problems importing images from one server to another, using Wordpress built in importer tool - You could also try this:

```
function github16702_allow_unsafe_urls($args, $url) {
    $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;
    return $args;
}
add_filter('http_request_args', 'github16702_allow_unsafe_urls', 20, 2 );
```

The function can be added to code snippets, or in the functions.php in your child theme. Tested and works.

Be sure to disable the code from running once the import is done, as Wordpress adds this code for safety measures.

The code above allows ALL url's that Wordpress wants to disallow because it believe it's an unsafe url.

Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/16702